# The content tree is hidden by default for all new users

Tags: content-tree

I am working on Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160302), I created a new role and added access rights on several items on it, I also made this role a member of (sitecore\Author), then I created a new user and assigned this new added role to him.

[image]

When I logged in with the new created user and access the content editor I found that the content tree is hidden

[image]

and the view tab is not exist on the Ribbon, when I right click on the Ribbon the view is not listed on the options as well so I am not able to show the View tab that contain the "Hidden items" checkbox, so I am able to test that the new added user is now have a privilege on a certain items depend on the roles that was assigned to him, any advise?

sample of the access rights

[image]

Comment: > "I created a new role and added access rights on several items" can you share the access rights screen shot too ? Looks like you are denying 'read' access on top level item.

Comment: @NaveedAhmad the read access is there, kindly take a look to the new added screenshot at the end of the question

Comment: @HudaAlMasoud - Your screenshot has cut off the items on the left so we cannot see what those permissions are referring to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable the View tab for your role by assigning Read access to the item `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/View` in the **core** database.

By default the `sitecore/Author` role has denied access to this tab.

A separate concern is whether your authors should be able to see this tab.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Roles and Security documentation on Sitecore's site: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles

While it's not entirely clear from the question what your goal is, to grant a user permission to use Content editor and Media Library, they should be assigned the Author role.

> **Author**
>
> Gives the user access to content in the content tree. This role
> provides access to basic item editing features, such as the Media
> Library and the Content Editor, with a reduced set of tabs on the
> ribbon.
>
> This role also has two of the Sitecore Client roles as members, so if
> you assign just this role to a user, the Sitecore Client Authoring and
> Sitecore Client Users roles will be automatically assigned to the
> user.

To access the View ribbon, they'll need the Sitecore Client Designing role. This role grants other privileges, however, that you may not wish the user to have.

> **Sitecore Client Designing**
>
> Gives the user access to Experience Editor
> Design pane features that allow a user to set layout details
> associated with items in the Sitecore client.

Once you've assigned these roles, you still need to set the security access rights on the home item and its descendants, as well as the media library. By default, no roles have write access to the content tree.  You can, for example, grant access to the Home item and its descendants to open up access to the Sitecore Client Authoring role.
[image: Security Editor]

Comment: thank you for this useful information the issue was solved by following the steps on "Szymon Kuzniak" comment

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to assign permission to a specific role for specific items. So for example there is a 'legal' division in the company who should only have access to certain items, while rest of the company should not have access.

By default, the sitecore roles are only meant to grant user access to features of the Content Editor and by default, the sitecore\author role has no write permission on the home node or child nodes

[image: default author role]

It is not a good practise to change security settings for pre-defined Sitecore roles, insetead create your own custom role and apply security settings. You need to create a custom role for the content section area or for the division (like legal) and assign that role basic write,create access etc. For example I created a 'division' role which has write, create and rename access.

[image: custom division role]

Then assign sitecore\author and sitecore\division role to the author user within the user manager

[image: author user with roles]

And when you login, you should have edit permission to the item

[image: logged in as author]